# Маршрутизация между vlan

Tags: сеть, iptables, маршрутизация

Имеется следующая схема сети:
[image: схема сети]
в iptables:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0.2 -o eth0.4 -s 192.168.2.0/24 -d 192.168.4.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0.4 -o eth0.2 -s 192.168.4.0/24 -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

На сервере CentOS 6.5
Проблема в том, что ПК 192.168.2.228 почему-то не получает ответы на пинг от ПК и роутера из vlan2, ответ от принтера приходит. В то же время сервер получает ответы от всех устройств.

Как заставить проходить пинги с vlan1 в vlan2 и обратно без проблем для всех устройств?

Answer (score 1):

То что не проходят пинги от определённых устройств говорит о том,
что эти устройства (скорее всего) просто не знают, куда посылать ответ.

Если маршрут в сеть 192.168.2.0/24 неизвестен на тех устройствах, с которых ответ не приходит, то именно в этом и заключается причина.

`iptables` в данном случае никак этому не мешает.

Чтобы убедиться в правильности данного предположения, вы можете:

1. Проверить маршруты на устройствах;
2. Запустить tcpdump на роутере и посмотреть, возвращаются ли ответы или нет.

Пример tcpdump:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0.2 -n icmp
```

В данном случае мы смотрим, идут ли ответы через интерфейс `eth0.2`.

**Обновление**

Вероятнее всего, что на устройствах, с которых не приходят ответы
просто не установлен маршрут по умолчанию.

Comment: Ответы с конечных устройств не идут, но с принтеров почему-то идут.
Таблицу маршрутизации ПК привёл выше (верная?).
Вот таблица маршрутизации роутера:
192.168.4.0(dest)
255.255.255.0(mask)
0.0.0.0(gw)

Comment: Неверная. dest должен быть `192.168.2.0`, а gw `192.168.4.1`

Comment: Теперь понятно, что проблема в таблицах, почему же у принтеров всё отлично?

Comment: Покажите таблицу маршрутизации принтера

Comment: @WaffRider: На узлах нет маршрута по умолчанию. В этом проблема

Comment: Вообще-то, по уму, маршрут по умолчанию должен вести на устройство, которое может смаршрутизировать дальше в Интернет. Если вот тот сервер к которому подключён транк не является выходом в Интернет, то на него направлять маршрут по умолчанию не стоит...

Comment: @mantigatos: про Интернет тут вообще речи же нет

Comment: @mantigatos
1. Таблицу маршрутизации принтера показать не могу, по причине, что он не умеет её показывать.
2. Маршрут на роутере, который я привёл выше разве не является по умолчанию? Был создан роутером самостоятельно...
3. Маршрут по умолчанию и ведёт на сервер, который является выходом в Интернет.

Comment: @WaffRider: не на роутере нужна таблица маршрутизации, а на клиентах, которые не пингуются!!! Мы про это спрашиваем. Принтеры не интересуют. С ними и так всё понятно.

Comment: @IgorChubin В данном случае клиентом выступает роутер `192.168.4.21`, он же и не пингуется.
Давайте называть главный роутер на CentOS - `сервер`

Comment: @WaffRider: вставьте, пожалуйста, отформатированный вывод route -n с машины 192.168.4.21 в текст вопроса. Тогда я вам точно скажу, что к чему

Comment: @mantigatos @Igor Chubin После прописывания дополнительного маршрута (dest-`192.168.2.0` gw-`192.168.4.1`) на `192.168.4.21` он стал отвечать хосту `192.168.2.228`
Не могу понять, почему `192.168.2.228` не отвечает роутеру
@Igor Chubin
На роутере не linux. Маршрут по умолчанию был таков: dest `192.168.4.0` mask `255.255.255.0` gw `0.0.0.0.`

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте установку маршрутов к `192.168.2.0/24` на тех устройствах  в в vlan2 от которых не проходят пинги. Очень похоже на то что неправильно натсроены таблицы маршрутизации.

Comment: route с 192.168.4.100 - default         192.168.4.1  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0.4

Comment: @WaffRider: что-то тут не так, потому что на устройстве у вас вообще не должно быть eth0.4. Проверьте